# D3D throws E_INVALIDARG only in debug mode, not in release

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, direct3d

I have the following code:

```
ID3D11Texture2D* depthTargetTexture;
ID3D11DepthStencilView* depthTargetDSV;

//CREATING DEPTH TARGET TEXTURE, DSV
CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthTargetTextureDescriptor;
depthTargetTextureDescriptor = CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC(DXGI_FORMAT_R32_TYPELESS, width, height);
depthTargetTextureDescriptor.MipLevels = 1;
depthTargetTextureDescriptor.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
result = device->CreateTexture2D(&depthTargetTextureDescriptor, 0, &depthTargetTexture);
if (result != S_OK) { Die(86251); }
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthTargetDSVDescriptor;
depthTargetDSVDescriptor.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;
depthTargetDSVDescriptor.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
depthTargetDSVDescriptor.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
result = device->CreateDepthStencilView(depthTargetTexture, &depthTargetDSVDescriptor, &depthTargetDSV);
if (result != S_OK) { Die(86225); }
//CREATING DEPTH TARGET TEXTURE, DSV
```

`Die()` is a simple function that throws me the error code and exits the program. This code throws `error 86225`, because `CreateDepthStencilView` returns with `E_INVALIDARG` in debug mode, but runs fine in release mode (`VS2015, Win10, x64`). Both `width` and `height` are correctly set to `1280` and `720`, that I checked, and this bit of code is not connected to anything else by any other variable.

Why is it throwing an error in debug mode?

Comment: A good practice is to zero out all the structures you pass to D3D functions - eg: `ZeroMemory(&depthTargetDSVDescriptor);`. There are different memory initialization rules between debug and release builds, which would explain the difference.

Comment: Don't use ``== S_OK`` or ``!= S_OK`` tests. Use the ``SUCCEEDED`` and ``FAILED`` macros. Better yet, use [ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed) with C++ exception handling enabled to deal with 'fast fatal' errors. Also, don't use raw pointers for your COM objects. Use a smart-pointer like [ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr).

Comment: Using VS 2013 or later (C++14 conforming compilers), you don't need old-school ``ZeroMemory``. Just use brace initialization: ``CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthTargetTextureDescriptor = {};``. In Release builds, uninitialized memory can be anything, In Debug, it's often ``0xcc`` filled.